# E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data [Value 60 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject] 60 (97)

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I am new to android programming. I am having a problem when i am trying to fetch data from mysql database in android using JSON. This my method. This is the error i receive: Value 60 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

```
private void getData(final String mac_Address){
    //Creating a string request
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_monitor";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_MONITOR_HEALTH_PARAMETERS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {

                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);
                        //boolean error = j.getBoolean("error");

                        //j = new JSONObject().append("userid", new JSONArray(json).getInt(0));
                        //boolean error = j.getBoolean("error");
                        //return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray("result");
                        //new JSONObject().append("pulse_rate", new JSONArray(result).getInt(0));
                        //JSONArray k = null;
                        for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++){
                            try {
                                //Getting json object
                                JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(i);

                                pulse_rate.add(json.getInt("pulse_rate"));
                                pulse_oxygen_saturation.add(json.getInt("pulse_oxygen_saturation"));
                                Log.d(TAG, "Fetching pulse rate from mysql: " +pulse_rate+" Fetching pulse rate from mysql: "+pulse_oxygen_saturation);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        //Calling method getMonitoringData to get the students from the JSON Array
                       // getMonitoringData(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage()+"] "+response);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }

            })
    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to monitor url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("mac_Address", mac_Address);
            return params;
        }

    };

    //Creating a request queue
    //RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);

    //Adding request to the queue
    //requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

This is my php code

```
$query = "SELECT pulse_rate, pulse_oxygen_saturation from health_para";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
$result1 = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
array_push($result1,array(
    'pulse_rate'=>$row[0],
    'pulse_oxygen_saturation'=>$row[1],
));
    //$response[]=$row;
    //echo json_encode($response);
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result1));
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
 }

 /* close connection */
 mysqli_close($link);

  } else {
 // required post params is missing
 $response["error"] = TRUE;
 $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters mac_address is missing!";
 echo json_encode($response);
 }
```

This is my JSON Response in my log:
This is what i have in my log:

```
 {
"result": [{
    "pulse_rate": "60",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "97"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "60",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "97"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "59",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "97"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "59",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "98"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "58",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "98"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "59",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "98"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "59",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "98"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "58",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "98"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "58",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "98"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "255",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "127"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "70",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "69",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "67",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "66",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "64",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "63",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "64",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "63",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "62",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "63",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "64",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "63",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "62",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "63",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "62",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "61",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "60",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "61",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "63",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "64",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "65",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "64",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "65",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "66",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "67",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "66",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "65",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "64",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "255",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "127"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "72",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "73",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "71",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "65",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "62",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "60",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "59",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "60",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "60",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "255",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "127"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "66",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "63",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "62",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "61",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}, {
    "pulse_rate": "60",
    "pulse_oxygen_saturation": "99"
}]
}
```

Comment: Please post your json response. There seems some difference in your json response and the way you are parsing it.

Comment: {"result":[{"pulse_rate":"60","pulse_oxygen_saturation":"97"}]}60 (97)
{"result":[{"pulse_rate":"60","pulse_oxygen_saturation":"97"},{"pulse_rate":"60","pulse_oxygen_saturation":"97"}]}59 (97)

Comment: It doesn't look like a valid JSON. Please post correct and valid JSON response.

Comment: I have posted it. Or may be there is something wrong with my php script

Comment: That's definitely not valid JSON.  Go to jsonlint.com and validate it, and you can see the problems.

Comment: I have validated the JSON

Comment: I have found my mistake

Comment: I am receiving this error: java.lang.NullPointerException pulse_rate.add(json.getInt("pulse_rate"));

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
pulse_rate.add(json.getString("pulse_rate"));
                            pulse_oxygen_saturation.add(json.getString("pulse_oxygen_saturation"));
```

Comment: I am receiving this error: java.lang.NullPointerException pulse_rate.add(json.getInt("pulse_rate"));